# Count number of rows where a value appears in any of two columns in R

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have a dataset like this:

```
data <- read.csv(text = "foo,bar
a,b
a,a
b,c
c,a
c,b")
```

I want to compute a table that tells me in how many rows every possible value appears, so something like this:

| Value | Count |
| --- | --- |
| a | 3 |
| b | 3 |
| c | 3 |

I've tried grouping by the two columns using dplyr and then summarise, but that does not give you a count per value, but per column value. Any idea?

Comment: Is the white space in the left column made by intention?

Comment: @GKi, no, it was not. Thanfully, it was edited away

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With `dplyr`, `tibble` and `tidyr`, you could do:

```
data %>%
 mutate(across(everything(), trimws)) %>%
 rowid_to_column() %>%
 pivot_longer(-rowid) %>%
 group_by(value) %>%
 summarise(n = n_distinct(rowid))

  value     n
  <chr> <int>
1 a         3
2 b         3
3 c         3
```

Answer (score 6):

Get `unique` per row, `unlist` the result and use `table` to get the counts.

```
table(unlist(apply(data, 1, unique)))
#a b c 
#3 3 3
```

Or the same but using pipes.

```
apply(data, 1, unique) |> unlist() |> table()
#a b c 
#3 3 3
```

Answer (score 5):

```
read.csv(text="foo,bar
 a,b
 a,a
 b,c
 c,a
 c,b", strip.white = TRUE) |>
  mutate(id = row_number()) |>
  pivot_longer(cols = -id) |>
  distinct(id, value) |>
  count(value)
# # A tibble: 3 × 2
#   value     n
#   <chr> <int>
# 1 a         3
# 2 b         3
# 3 c         3
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

data %>% 
  mutate(bar1 = ifelse(foo==bar, NA_character_, bar)) %>% 
  pivot_longer(-bar, values_drop_na = TRUE) %>% 
  count(value)

  value     n
  <chr> <int>
1 a         3
2 b         3
3 c         3
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `table` + `rowSums`

```
> rowSums(table(unlist(data), c(row(data))) > 0)
a b c
3 3 3
```

## Data

```
> dput(data)
structure(list(foo = c("a", "a", "b", "c", "c"), bar = c("b", 
"a", "c", "a", "b")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,
-5L))
```